# Does Sencha Touch allow direct manipulation of DOM and canvas elements?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, integration

Does Sencha Touch integrate well with code that directly manipulates the DOM and/or <canvas>? In my case specifically, I have an app that uses KineticJS for several GUI components that need to be responsive or high frame rate. I'm also using WebAudio and reqAnimFrame, both of which assume things about the execution lifecycle (or, well, my code assumes things in how it schedules these). Are such things going to be impossible, difficult, easy to integrate with a Sencha app?

**Longer version**

I am investigating Sencha, having become frustrated with the patchwork approach to JS libraries in a hybrid app. I now have an app that has some impressive functionality but is starting to feel like it cannot stretch beyond refined prototype, as the available libraries add so much technical debt integrating and wrestling to get them to do what I want. GUI In particular is very difficult. What I'm wanting is just proving too cumbersome using tools focused on general purpose web apps. HTML declarative widgets and layout, lots of CSS, external SVG, custom canvas components... Hybrid apps are Frankenstein monsters, at least if they go beyond typical CRUD apps with list views and standard mobile UI (and often even then).

Sencha clearly is very robust, mature, and capable -- potentially a good investment for future projects. However I desperately am trying to get this current project back on track, where I can focus on adding features and less on the plumbing. I'd *happily* invest a few weeks just getting up to speed with a new (to me) technology like Sencha if I knew it would be possible and not prohibitively difficult to integrate my existing code, or (and I'm not seeing this), if there is some Sencha-preferred way to do high-performance rendering and scheduling.

Hopefully this question is clear and not perceived as subjective. I believe it's an objective question (maybe not absolute *yes* or *no*), but requires some real experience with Sencha to be able to answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can clearly do all of this with Sencha.

Though you might will need some additional help at the beginning.

Usually you can wrap everything inside the MVC from Senchas folders, but for this never was enough, as I have a lot of code outside this.

E.g. all my Ajax calls are inside the folder app/util/ajax as they can be called from different places.
Instead of adding the ajax calls inside the controllers I prefer to place them at a place I think everyone will find them, even after I finish my work.

Then I usually need an initialization of the apps inside app/util/initialize ...

But you should be able to do all you mentioned quite easy after some time.

Sencha is quick to learn on a low level. Next step takes quite some time and after that all comes to you ...

Further there is a quite good community around Sencha and Sencha Touch.

Hope this helps